# Access the value using pointer in Ada

Tags: ada, abstract-data-type

I am somewhat new in Ada and having some difficulties with the syntax of this language.

I've implemented a stack, and to push a value to it, for example, I need to use a function `Push(Stack_instance, value)`.

I need many such stack instances, not of a fixed size. So I thought to use pointer to stack, which will create new stack object every time I need one.

Now, the problem I have is that after creating a pointer to stack that points to a new stack, how can I push a value to this stack instance? I can't use `Push(Stack, value)` since the `Push` function requires type `Stack` and I have `Ptr_Stack`. For example, in C, we have `*ptr` through which we can access value, but is there anything similar in Ada?

Comment: The usual advice regarding Ada and access types: Hide your use of access types inside the package.  Avoid making the users of the package have to think about memory management.

Comment: More advice regarding Ada and access types: don’t use them at all unless you have to! You can pass a `Stack` as an `in out` parameter; something like a C++ reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do:

```
Push (Stack.all, Value);
```

If you are using Ada 2005 or more recent, and your stack type is a tagged type, you can also use the slightly more user-friendly:

```
Stack.Push (Value);
```

Finally, you can also change the declaration of Push to accept a pointer to a stack, as in:

```
procedure Push (Stack : not null access Stack_Type; Value : ...);
Push (Stack, Value);
```